# Css selectors and selecting specific element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a table with this form

```
<table class="myclass">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="7">something</th>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5</th>
            <th>6</th>
            <th>7</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        etc...
```

I want to apply a css rule only to the th with something. That is the descedant of tr which in turn is the first descendant of thead which in turn is descendant of table with myclass I use this css selector

```
table.myclass thead > tr th{
    background-color:red;
}
```

but is also applied in all the other th's in the thead (1, 2, 3, etc). Have i missunderstood the selector thing?

Any good tutorials about advanced selectors?

And a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3P9nT/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that you only want to select the `th` that is the descendent of the `tr` that is the *first child* of the `thead`:

```
table.myclass thead > tr:first-child th
```

ref: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3P9nT/1/

Answer (score 0):

As your requirement, you only want to apply CSS for first `tr > th` . So for this you can use [`:first-child`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/) css selecter:

```
table.myclass thead > tr:first-child th{
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4R3HF/)

[Your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3P9nT/2/)